# Python Pandas: Using a map function within a lambda / TypeError: ("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'"

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, typeerror

I'm new to Python and Pandas and struggling with one DataFrame for quite some time. Spend some research and read many forums, but still not able to resolve it. Among other things, right now I'm **trying to convert every element of a Series of Lists from Str to Int**. After some research, consider using the **map-function within a lambda** for every row by applying the axis = 1 within an apply-statement.

For some reason, however, the map function gets confused as it does not refer to the single row as a list. When applied on a single row with an additional index constraint like `df['Column1'][1]`, it appears to work all right, however, does not make the link with the axis as expected without the `[1]`.
As a result, I get an error message as follows:
`#TypeError: ("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'", 'occurred at index 0')` .
Probably I miss some special syntax, a reference to the link, or it simply does not work the way I think it should. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciated! Many thanks in advance!

P.S. There are also some additional complications due to missing values (nan) which are of type float. As the Series is a mixture between List and Float, some commands and functions does not work, thus needed to apply an if-condition within the lambda. I did it in 2 steps in the end, as the notnull() did not work within the lambda statement on a single row...

Below a simple code which should illustrate the DataFrame and what I'm trying to do.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([['1'],['2','2'],['3','4','5'],np.nan]), columns = ['Column1'])


df['Empty_flag'] = df['Column1'].notnull()

#As a single component it works well.
list(map(int, df['Column1'][1]))

#When applied on the entire series, however, it returns an error message
df['Column2'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(map(int, df['Column1'])) if x['Empty_flag'] else None ,axis=1)

#TypeError: ("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: When you say "as a single component it works well" you're not actually mutating the data frame there. You're just creating a list outside of it.

Comment: Yes, it was just to illustrate what i'm trying to do. Within the dataframe would be similar to this `df['Column2'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(map(int, df['Column1'][1]) if x['Empty_flag'] else None ,axis=1)
`, however, it is a nonsense as it applies always the same content from the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([['1'],['2','2'],['3','4','5'],np.nan]), columns = ['Column1'])
df['Empty_flag'] = df['Column1'].notnull()
df['Column2'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x['Column1'])) if x['Empty_flag'] else None ,axis=1)
>>> df
     Column1  Empty_flag    Column2
0        [1]        True        [1]
1     [2, 2]        True     [2, 2]
2  [3, 4, 5]        True  [3, 4, 5]
3        NaN       False       None
>>> type(df["Column2"][0][0])
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got it myself too! needed to replace the df['] with x[] in the lambda statement. A newbie's mistake :).

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! Happens to everyone at some point haha